# Add rows values of a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of three times in the format of Minute:Seconds:Miliseconds which I need to add to together and get the total time..

for example the one I have used is : **0:31.110 + 0:50.490 + 0:32.797** 
which = **1:54.397**

so how to do this in javascript?

Here is JS Code

```
var sp1 = $('#table tr td:nth-child(2)').text()
var sp2 = $('#table tr td:nth-child(3)').text()
var sp3 = $('#table tr td:nth-child(4)').text()
var1 = sp1 + sp2 + sp3
$('td:nth-child(5)').html(var1);
```

I don't know where to begin but I have just come up with the above code..
I need the output to be **1:54.397** in the last td, but I get this 0:31.1100:50.4900:32.797 shown in this example http://jsfiddle.net/q1kumbea/

Comment: well, you can simply break it up with the split method and do the math

Comment: you need to split the time and then add each component seprately like t1.split(":"), t2.split(":"), t3.split(":") then t1[0] +t2[0] +t3[0] ... and at the end join them again with colon (:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this. That would make it very easy, as you can just parse the times in the correct format, add the `moments` together ...

```
var sp1 = $('#table tr td:nth-child(2)').text()
var sp2 = $('#table tr td:nth-child(3)').text()
var sp3 = $('#table tr td:nth-child(4)').text()
var1 = moment(sp1, "mm:ss.SSS") + moment(sp2, "mm:ss.SSS") + moment(sp3, "mm:ss.SSS")
 $('td:nth-child(5)').html(moment(var1).format("mm:ss.SSS"));
```

... and voila

[image]

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1kumbea/1/)

Comment: Perfect! just what I wanted.

Comment: You might wanna use a variable for the date format, so you don't have to repeat it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any native functionality, but you can always(almost:) ) use some maths to achieve what you want. like below

```
var plusTimes = function(arr) {
var resultTime =0;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
resultTime += (parseInt((arr[i].split(':')[0]) * 60  * 1000) + ( parseInt(arr[i].split(':')[1].split('.')[0]) * 1000 ) + parseInt(arr[i].split('.')[1])) 

}
var ms = (resultTime / 1000).toString().split('.')[1];
var sec = parseInt((resultTime / 1000).toString().split('.')[0]) % 60;
var min = (parseInt((114397 / 1000).toString().split('.')[0]) - parseInt((114397 / 1000).toString().split('.')[0]) % 60) / 60;

return min + ':' + sec + '.' + ms;

}
plusTimes(['0:31.110','0:50.490', '0:32.797']) // outputs "1:54.397"
```

you can add as many numbers as you wish to array unless you keep their format the same